# Wanting to learn/run PHP Unit Tests however realised I have old version of PHP

Tags: php

After writing some code in PHP I want to learn the best way to run unit tests against my code. I found a couple such as PHPUnit and SimpleTest but in the documentation I could see they were talking about PHP 7.0 +.

I checked which version of PHP I was running and it looks to be a very old version:

```
PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Oct 29 2017 20:30:32) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

However when I open my MAMP is states `7.2.10`

If I were to install a newer version of PHP on my `MACOS Sierra 10.12.6` would this effect the running of my old PHP code (Note I am also running MAMP Version 5.2)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check the link https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.php. Just search for migration from php 5.6 to any php version you want to migrate.